# Video doesn't have EOS

Tags: java, android, video

I made real time recorder application. It works very well. But, there is a small problem. I found a reason why it doesn't work. Video that I record doesn't have EOS.

I added :

```
MediaCodec.signalEndOfInputStream();
```

But It doesn't work I think.
I even tried adding twice but Logcat said:

*"Already added inputEndOfStream"*.

Comment: Maybe this Answer helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222059/mediacodec-signalendofinputstream-error

Comment: Thanks for adding comment. But I don't understand your answer. Your answer is using WORK_AROUND_BUGS. what is WORK_AROUND_BUGS? when is WORK_AROUND_BUGS true?